# When should / shouldn't we use Ember Model for displaying data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-model

I would generally like to understand, when should we use Ember Model to storing data and when should we declare data within components to be used by templates for rendering?

For instance, I have a report component and the associated template shows the fields and values entered by the user. The report template is rendered only when clicked on a button to explicitly display the report.

So, currently on the initial render of the component, I fetch the values from an API and pre-fill the report using the returned values. And as the user edits and saves, the save API takes in the changed values and update the report.

Since the report is not going to persist, I'm not storing the added values in an Ember Model, and also, on every click when the report is opened, an API is called to fetch the values. I don't see the reason to define an Ember Model for this. In fact, I'm using an Ember Object, which maintains the values at a component level.

I'm fairly new to Ember, so I just want to ask is this a wrong practice to not maintain the API response at the model data level?

Should we define an Ember Model for every API call?

For POST/PUT calls, how should we maintain data in an Ember App?

Please suggest the best practices for handling such cases.

Comment: Hi, Son, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, you will have better luck getting your questions answered if they are fact based and not a matter of opinion, as "best practices" usually are. I will say that ember-model is not a widely used addon. You may be referring to ember-data, which uses models as well. ember-data can significantly simplify and help organize your code, if you are using a RESTful api and especially if the format conforms to the json-api specification. However, it is not always appropriate and it is certainly ok to use Ember without ember-data.

Comment: In addition, it is ok to use ember-data for some api calls but not others. An api call where you don't persist data is especially a good candidate for not using ember-data or creating a model. I hope this wall of text helps.